# Enzyme kinetics calculation

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

How to calculate or determine enzymatic activity?
The only information that I have are the substrates concentrations and the absorbance.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry StackExchange. To get an answer you will need to add some more details. The only thing that is definite at present is that concentration is directly proportional to absorbance.

Comment: If it is a spectrophotometric assay, you will need to know the extinction coefficient of the product and/or substrate you are monitoring at the wavelength of the assay.  Almost certainly you will need to calculate the _intial_ rate of reaction.     [Principles of enzyme assay and kinetic studies](https://books.google.ie/books?id=W-KAirjgqdQC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=Enzyme+assays+and+kinetic+studies&source=bl&ots=ucAs8WP00u&sig=OgVWUgZSLjDx0se0pCxwB05xSCY&hl=ga&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-ncKenJLSAhUYOsAKHYxQBDQQ6AEIITAC#v=onepage&q=Enzyme%20assays%20and%20kinetic%20studies&f=false)